# illustrator CS6: can't wrap text around object

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text-wrap

I manually drew some shapes and grouped them. Then I was trying to put them on top of a text box and let the texts avoid those shapes by choosing Object→Arrange→Bring to Front and choosing Object→Text Wrap→Make. However the texts were still behind the shapes. I've searched for online solutions but nothing worked. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you include an image as well?

Comment: @WELZ Already solved and thank you for your quick response!

Answer (score 1):

Alright I found the answer to my own question.
The reason was that the text and the image were not on the same layer.
There are requirements for text-wrapping to happen:
Text and object MUST be on the same layer.
Text MUST be on top of object to be wrapped.
Text MUST be area text.

To play with layers, here is a good guide:
https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/layers.html